# Can I use mysql's built-in function get_lock?

Tags: mysql, locking, distributed-system

There is a batch job outside. And there are multiple servers which can process the job.
I want only one server among many servers to fetch and process the job at specific times.

For this purpose, while investigating the global locking mechanism, I found mysql's get_lock function.

Also, since there is already a dependency on mysql, I think I can use this function.

However, what is suspicious is that, when looking for the global locking mechanism, most of them use redis, etc., and it was difficult to find cases that use get_lock.

So I doubt there is any downside to mysql's get_lock.

My current situation is that mysql is already being used, but rather redis is not being used.

Then, can I use mysql's get_lock for global locking?
Or maybe is there a downside to mysql's get_lock?

Answer (score 1):

Already voted to close this, but a few pointers might be helpful.

As I understand it, you have several machines processing the same dataset - you want to ensure exclusivity on data items. You seem to be considering an advisory locking mechanism, i.e. one in which data consumers need to go looking for locks then create them before using data. Advisory locking should only be used as a last resort:

- data clients need to explicitly opt-in to the locking mechanism - as systems become more complex it becomes increasing likely that someone will write some code which fails to use the locking mechanism in the same way as everything else. Then stuff breaks
- advisory locking leads to displaced state - the lock state is held in a different place from the action requiring the lock. You're now in land of CAP theorem

Try re-posting with details of the data sinks and sources and the resources available rather than asking if a solution is appropriate to an undefined problem.